# Error when input cd C:

Tags: ruby

So I'm reading "Ruby Wizardry" by Eric Weinstein and I'm up to the script part and when I input: `cd C:\Users\Ender\ruby`, Ruby responds with `"SyntaxError: <irb>:7: syntax error, unexpected $undefined cd C:\Users\Ender\ruby"` What's the syntax error? I input everything as the book said. I have Ruby 2.0.0-p645. Can anyone help, I would appreciate it! BTW, I have .rb files on standby ready for reading and the file exists. The proper command is Dir.chdir DIRECTORY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as `cd` in Ruby. I suspect you might have mistook it as Ruby code, while it's really a command line command.

Answer (score 0):

You should be entering that command at the shell (DOS) prompt.

You somehow seem to be entering it at a ruby prompt instead.

Either the book has skipped a step, or you have.